# C: Public aliases to hide a static function

Tags: c, encapsulation, abstraction

In C, I have a function that implements both the encryption and decryption routines of a block cipher. In order to both maintain a common naming and use convention, and to leave open the possibility of separating the routines into two different functions later, I've done the following:

```
void cipher(char *out, const char *in);
#define encrypt    cipher
#define decrypt    cipher
```

That works fine, except that I'd really like to hide the actual function (`cipher`) so people have to use `encrypt` or `decrypt`. Right now, `cipher` is part of the public interface, so if I decide to separate it into two different functions later and delete `cipher`, strictly speaking, I'm breaking the interface. But if I can hide `cipher` so only `encrypt` and `decrypt` are part of the interface, I'll be fine.

The only option I've come up with so far is make `cipher` static, and implement actual functions for `encrypt` an `decrypt` to call `cipher`, but I'm not sure that the added overhead is actually worth it (I'm trying to keep the code size as tight as possible, and I have multiple occurrences of this same problem).

Is there something I can do with function pointers? Any other ideas?

Comment: How about defining `encrypt` and `decrypt` in the header file as static inline functions that call `cipher`? That would give you source compatibility (just because `cipher` is in the symbol table doesn't mean it's in the API), but of course not binary compatibility if you later remove `cipher` from a dll.

Comment: Oh and btw, if an additional call to a do-nothing wrapper function creates measurable overhead, then your block cipher is weak ;-p

Comment: @Steve: Well, that does works, but with a warning ("implicit declaration of function 'cipher'"). And in that case, someone can still call `cipher` directly. It's not in the header file, so I guess that's there problem for screwing around, but it's kind of unclean to me. If I mark `cipher` as `static` to prevent this, it won't link.

Comment: @Steve: Not sure what you mean about the cipher being weak. Thinking timing attacks? The overhead I'm concerned about is code space, not execution time.

Comment: @bmearns:  he means that the cipher function itself is likely to be large in both memory footprint and computationally intensive unless the cipher being implemented is weak.  Adding the overhead of two wrapper functions is going to be pretty insignificant.

Comment: @JeremyP: Ah, yeh, that's a reasonably fair assumption. One of my ciphers is XTEA, so it's pretty small, but still large compared to the overhead of a wrapper function. I'll go with either this or Jerry Coffin's answer, below.

Comment: @bmearns: JeremyP is right about what I meant. I didn't intend for you to get that implicit declaration, though - I was thinking that you'd still declare `cipher` in the header, just don't document it as part of the guaranteed interface. Some people might say, "I'll poke around in the header and call anything I find there, even if there's a comment there saying 'this is an internal function'". But they're wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use function pointers:

```
static void cipher(...);

void (*encrypt)(...) = cipher;
void (*decrypt)(...) = cipher;
```

At least in typical use (the user just uses `encrypt(whatever);`) this wouldn't normally be visible. The only obvious problem would be that as defined above, the pointers remain writable, so you might want to make them `const` so the user can't accidentally overwrite them with the address of some other function.

Another possibility would be to live with the name `cipher` being public (or rename it to something like `private_cipher_` to avoid accidental name collisions) and then just use a couple of macros:

```
#define encrypt(x, y) private_cipher_((x), (y))
#define decrypt(x, y) private_cipher_((x), (y))
```

This should ensure against any overhead.

Comment: The macro is what I'm using now, but I'd prefer to hide `cipher`. I think using the function pointers will be my best bet. I tested it out, it works fine, I can mark `encrypt` and `decrypt` as `const` so they aren't modifiable, and I can mark `cipher` as `static` so it's not importable. It only adds a little bit of overhead, but it does it where it's called, not where it's defined, so I'll have to decide which is a better trade off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GCC, you can use the [`alias` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to make two aliases that point to your `cipher` function.

But take Steve Jessop's comment in mind and consider just writing two wrapper functions.  It shouldn't cause noticeable overhead.  The compiler might even write those wrapper functions as a single jump instruction.

Answer (score 0):

In GCC (and compatible) lands, you can also use the attribute fluff for controlling symbol visibility, versioning and aliasing:

```
static void xxx_encrypt_decrypt(char *y, const char *x) { ... }
void encrypt(char *, const char *) __attribute__((alias("xxx_encrypt_decrypt")));
void decrypt(char *, const char *) __attribute__((alias("xxx_encrypt_decrypt")));
```